# how to convert python script to executable with pyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pywebview

I am trying to make the .exe for this code but i am unable to do that. I am using PyInstaller to make the .exe it make the .exe file but the file prompts an error 
Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.

This is how my code looks like

```
import webview

def connect(url):
    window = webview.create_window('My Page', url)
    webview.start(process_check,window,gui='cef')

if internet_on() is 'True':
    connect_zoom('Link to website')
else:
    window = webview.create_window('KNS Institute Online', html='<h1>This is initial HTML</h1>')
    webview.start(gui = 'cef')
```

Comment: Why would you ever use Python as exe file??

Comment: I need to make my python script to be executable without having python installed in any computer

Comment: I tied something similar a while ago with PyInstaller and it wasn't possible. You have to have Python installed on comp to run exe if I remember correctly.

Comment: Then how we can deliver the product to end user ??

Answer (score 0):

python -m eel app.py templete --onefile --noconsole --icon=1.ico

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.